# Los borradores de respuestas, ¿se pierden si OP elimina la pregunta?

Tags: soporte, eliminación-de-preguntas

Ayer @ceravieja hizo una pregunta interesante sobre oraciones condicionales, que empecé a responder en borrador y que iba a completar hoy con nuevas ideas que me parecían útiles para el sitio.

El usuario borró la pregunta: ¿existe alguna posibilidad de que, si OP reactiva la pregunta, se recupere la respuesta en borrador?

Comment: Si vas a https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35587/1674 (es decir, la pregunta borrada), ¿no ves tu borrador?

Comment: No, no lo veo...

Comment: Falta uno voto _undelete_ por reabrir la pregunta.

Comment: Anda, pensaba que eran necesarios cinco y voté para probarlo. El mío fue el tercero y ya se recuperó, @mdewey. Siento el voto, pues como decía en mi respuesta si el usuario quiso eliminarla yo casi que la dejaría borrada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pregunté en Meta SE ([Are answer drafts kept if a question is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353690/209901)) y [explican](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353692/209901) que el borrador debería estar aún disponible si se recupera la pregunta. Por tanto, no se borran al eliminarse la pregunta.

Nótese que la [documentación sobre los borradores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/209901) explica que se borran pasados siete días. Por tanto es recomendable no apurar mucho los tiempos y mejor sincronizarse con un moderador para que recupere la pregunta en un momento en el que puedas copiar el borrador, para así poder volver a borrarla manteniendo la voluntad de quien la formuló y luego borró.

Finalmente, si la respuesta que ibas escribiendo te parece especialmente útil, recomiendo que tú mismo formules la pregunta para dar pie a publicar la respuesta. De este modo no se pierde tan útil información. (La de libros que se han perdido por nimiedades... ayer mismo leyendo *Salvar el fuego* hablaban de ello)

Comment: Gracias por tu esfuerzo y por permitirme visualizar la pregunta borrada, que utilizaré para hacer una "autopregunta". Lo que había redactado como respuesta era sólo la introducción (que había quedado guardada como Draft saved) y lo que quería agregar, que me parecía interesante, es una teoría en parte basada en las distintas funciones del lenguaje como justificación para modificar los tiempos verbales habituales de las oraciones condicinales (similar a lo que ocurre en inglès).

Comment: Si sabes que acaban de borrar una publicación, en Spanish.SE (o cualquier sitio pequeño) es fácil buscarla teniendo en cuenta que cada publicación tiene un identificador consecutivo. En este caso, fui a https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/35585/timeline (pregunta algo anterior) y fui cambiando el 35585 por uno más hasta llegar a la de CeraVieja